# Method importing parameter type range of any

Tags: abap

I am trying to build a dynamic method and I need to pass any range table to it. So I want to make sure a) only a range can be passed or b) I leave the processing if the provided table is not a range. So my question would be:

Is there a way to define a method so the importing parameter has to be a range table (**any type of range table**)?

If there isn't any good was I would do it like this to check if the importet table is a range.

1) I would check for a table header.

```
Methods: this_method
  IMPORTING
    i_table TYPE any table.

IF i_table IS INITIAL.
  "do some code
ENDIF.
```

If this doesn't work I'll take the longer way.

2) I would use cl_abap_*descr classes to find out if the passed table has fields named "sign", "option", "low", high".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of "any range table" typed parameter.

Your second option with [`RTTS`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrtti.htm) would work.

Another option with a better performance that can only approve if the parameter is not of range table type, is to assign `SIGN`, `OPTION` etc... components of the first line if exists and then check `IS NOT ASSIGNED`.

Comment: I did a test (7.52): the performance of ASSIGN is not better than RTTS if you do a complete check whether an internal table is a ranges table or not (check = first four fields must be sign 1C, option 2C, low, high, with low and high of the same type and length, I used DESCRIBE FIELD with ASSIGN). If you consider only testing the component names (so it might not be a valid ranges table), then ASSIGN is x3 faster than RTTS.